# Android Class.forName from library class

Tags: java, android

I need to create an Object using Class.forName("classname").newInstance() where classname is a class inside a library correctly imported into my app, but it's not working (classNotFoundException).

I tried by setting classname = path (i.e. /Project/src/package/Class) but it's not working either.

How do I reference the class? It works if the class is inside my project so I guess it's because it's inside a library.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried to instantiate it explicitly to check whether the library is correctly included in the apk?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I reference the class?

By its `fully.qualified.class.name.IncludingThePackage`.

Note that you may need to teach ProGuard not to obfuscate the name of this class for your release builds.